# Typing tutor games with good playablity

Tags: software-recommendation, keyboard, games

Are there any linux typing tutor games which are enjoyable games in their own right?

I'm a computer professional, but have never learned to type properly. I also don't want my kids to pick up my bad habits! The kids are okay with [TuxTyping](http://tux4kids.alioth.debian.org/tuxtype/index.php), for a time. Something like [Typing of the Dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead) sounds great, but is Windows only, and as far as I can tell one of a kind. I also don't want the young'uns hooked on first person shooters just yet.

So are there any quality typing games for a range of ages?

Comment: Tux Typing is so much fun <3

Comment: TotD isn't really an FPS in the traditional sense, even if you take away the keyboard and replace it with a gun (as in HotD 2). It's also a great game for learning to type, so don't overlook the suggestion to try it with Wine! Having said that, if you're actually looking to type properly (finger placement, etc) as opposed to speed up your typing, you're better off with a more tutor-like application. TotD just presents you with words to type, it doesn't tell you how to type them.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried playing *Typing of the Dead* using [wine](http://www.winehq.org/)? It has a [gold rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6906) which means it should run fine.

Comment: anyone know where the PC version of ToD can be purchased?

Comment: This is an old comment and you've likely already found a solution or given up, but I'm installing ToD via steam (running steam under wine) -- `winetricks steam`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind online flash games, I find Typer Shark to be pretty enjoyable. It's best if you've already done typing tutorials "properly" to give you an idea of what you should be doing, but is a very good way to practice.

Comment: +1 for Typer Shark. One of the few typing games that's actually entertaining in its own right, alongside Typing of the Dead. Also good suggestion to do tutorials beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best typing game I've ever played http://phoboslab.org/ztype/

Comment: this is amazing

Answer (score 2):

**[OMG! Words!](https://github.com/Nevon/OMG--Words-/)**

[image]

> OMG! Words! is free, cheesy and somewhat addictive. Better still it’s easy to play.If you have an internet connection OMG! Words! will pull glean a list of words from recent posts for you to ‘battle’ against (If you don’t have an internet connection then it just uses magic).

[From OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/omg-words-a-free-game-for-linux-with-my-face-in/)

**Installation**

Add the PPA `ppa:tommybrunn/omgwords` and `ppa:bartbes/love-stable` To your Software Sources ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) and install omgwords from the Software Center.

Comment: I doubt it'll pique kids' interest...

Comment: @Oxwivi "The kids are okay with TuxTyping" he wants something for him.

Comment: Ah, oops, my bad, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net/search/?q=typing&section=projects&Go.x=0&Go.y=0)

Answer (score 1):

While using games to improve typing for the kids may be a good idea, I still feel that you shouldn't neglect the basics.  There are a number of typing tutors for Linux.  A couple of really good ones include TIPP10 http://www.tipp10.com/en/ and KTouch http://ktouch.sourceforge.net/

There are a number of Web based sources that are also available.  A good one you can try is Touch Typing School http://www.touchtypingschool.com/ The site has a couple of game based typing tutors available, one based on Tetris and the other on Arkenoid/Breakout.

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several programs:
GNU Typist - very ugly :) Just a console

I like "Klavaro". Looks pretty, interface is quite good. Also KTouch for KDE. Don't like it, but this software has some bonuses: e.g. typing diagram.

But now I prefer on-line services. There are a lot of game for kids and not only for kids.
10fastfingers.com or http://keyboard-racing.com.