# Are there any good programs to learn Dvorak?

Tags: software-recommendation, dvorak

How do I learn Dvorak typing in Ubuntu?
I'm planning to learn one of the [Swedish dvorak versions](http://tlundqvist.org/sv_dvorak/) included in Ubuntu.

Is there a good program to learn dvorak (sv)? I've linked the version that I want to learn and I really need a picture of the keyboard setup. Because I can't see the layout at the moment.

**ktouch** doesn't support my version of dvorak, and **klarvo** doesn't show a picture of the keyboard.

Comment: I don't know about games, but the swedish dvorak layout you linked is supported as the "Sweden sdvorak" keyboard layout.

Comment: I know, I'm asking if there is a program that I can learn it from like a game or just a program. it MUSTN'T be a game! Just a program!

Comment: See also, http://askubuntu.com/questions/14673/typing-tutor-games-with-good-playablity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any existing typing program (say, `junior-typing` or `klavaro`) and run with it.

http://klavaro.sourceforge.net/en/

Comment: klarvo didn't work.

Comment: I guess my point is, you don't need a dvorak typing program, you need any typing program. Or, you need a swedish typing program so you have the special characters.

Comment: true, and then just have a keyboard picture next to it.. Well I'm still looking...

Answer (score 3):

I learned Dvorak using [TypeFaster](http://www.typefastertypingtutor.com/) for Windows.

On Linux, [ktouch](http://ktouch.sourceforge.net/) is supposed to be very good, or there is [gtypist](http://www.gnu.org/software/gtypist/) if the others aren't suitable.

KTouch comes with a configuration file called `sv.dvorak.keyboard`, so I think it will work for you.

See also: https://superuser.com/questions/541/is-there-any-software-to-help-me-learn-the-dvorak-layout

---

**UPDATE**

sv.dvorak is supported in older versions of KTouch.  To get it to work in the current version, try this:

1. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktouch/files/ktouch/1.6/ktouch-1.6.0.tar.gz/download
2. Open ktouch-1.6.0.tar.gz
3. Navigate to /ktouch-1.6.0/ktouch/keyboards/
4. Click on sv.dvorak.keyboard
5. Extract...
6. Save somewhere (e.g. ~/Downloads)
7. Follow these instructions http://edu.kde.org/ktouch/kde4/keyboards-layouts.php

Comment: ktouch worked, but it isn't that great really, it hasn't support for sv dvorak only us. when I looked in the language selections I couldn't find sv.dvorak.

Comment: You can import sv.dvorak.keyboard using the instructions at http://edu.kde.org/ktouch/kde4/keyboards-layouts.php.  I added details to my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Or make it fun!
http://www.phoboslab.org/ztype/
In this R-Type-like game you shoot things by typing words written on them.

Comment: That's awesome! :D I love it!

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has a decent console-based Dvorak tutor.  To install:

```
sudo apt-get install dvorak7min
```

Then, to run just type `dvorak7min` at a console.

By the way, to enable the Dvorak layout from the console, use:

```
setxkbmap dvorak
```

To turn it off and go back to another layout (e.g. qwerty), you can do something like:

```
setxkbmap us
```