# Are there any good typing tutors?

Tags: software-recommendation, education

Are there any good typing tutor applications available for Ubuntu?

Comment: did you already search "typing" in the Ubuntu Software Center? It comes up with a couple of them.

Comment: This isn't a tutor, but it surely tests you: `sudo apt-get install typespeed`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**[Klavaro](http://klavaro.com/)**([Click to install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/klavaro))

**Or install from the command line with**

```
sudo apt-get install klavaro
```

**Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) or later**

```
sudo apt install klavaro
```

> Klavaro is a simple tutor to teach correct typing, almost independently of language and very flexible regarding to new or unknown keyboard layouts.
>   Its key features are:
>   * Internationalization
>   * Ready to use keyboard layouts
>   * Keyboard layout editor
>   * Basic course
>   * Adaptability, velocity and fluidness exercises
>   * Progress charts.

Screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Adaptability practice registers backspace as a keypress and doesn't allow me to correct mistakes. Quite annoying, I don't recommend this app.

Answer (score 6):

**[OMG! Words!](https://github.com/Nevon/OMG--Words-/)**

[image]

> OMG! Words! is free, cheesy and somewhat addictive. Better still it’s easy to play.If you have an internet connection OMG! Words! will pull glean a list of words from recent posts for you to ‘battle’ against (If you don’t have an internet connection then it just uses magic).

[From OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/omg-words-a-free-game-for-linux-with-my-face-in/)

**Installation**

Add the PPAs `ppa:tommybrunn/omgwords` and `ppa:bartbes/love-stable` to your Software Sources ([Here's how to do that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/5102#5102)) and install omgwords from the Software Center.

Answer (score 4):

I have been happy with Klavaro.  It is better than previous tutors I have tried.

Answer (score 4):

ktouch is a great application for this purpose.

There are also a quick game named tux typing :-)

For my purpose I use [this program](http://www.maurorossi.net/tutoredattilo/pagine/download.htm) with wine. Maybe work with natty. Is available also in english language. Is not GPL.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [Tipp10](http://www.tipp10.com/de/download/). 
It's a really good program.

[The Tipp 10 site.](http://www.tipp10.com/de/download/)

Comment: In its newest version, it has also got an english interface.

Comment: i installed it with sudo dpkg -i filename.deb, but when i launch it from apps it does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

Type-Fu (http://type-fu.com/) is available as an OSX app and as a chrome addon.

The killer feature from my perspective was that is supports multiple keyboard layouts, including Dvorak and Coleman, whereas more typing tutors are designed around QWERTY layouts.