# How to save after editting 'vi common.mak' (aircrack-ng) on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, 12.04, aircrack-ng

I followed the steps from here >> http://securit.se/en/2012/03/kompilera-reaver-ubuntu-12-04/

everything was going good till I reached this point.

after I found the following lines in the file

```
CFLAGS   ?= -g -W -Wall -Werror -O3
```

and edited it to make it like this >>

```
CFLAGS  ?= -g -W -Wall -O3
```

But then I am supposed to save the file, how?. when I close the terminal I was expecting them to prompt 'save file before exit' but it does not, theres just 2 options 'cancel' and 'close terminal'

HOW DO I SAVE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get out of insert mode, and then do `:wq` to write the file and quit.

But in general you don't have to use vi - when you see it in instructions on the web, use `nano` (edit in terminal) or `gedit` (GUI editor) instead. When you typed:

```
vi common.mak
```

You were launching the vi editor to edit the file `common.mak`. Instead you could do:

```
nano common.mak
```

or

```
gedit common.mak
```

to edit the file in an editor that doesn't require learning to do simple things like saving a file.

Or if you want to learn vi then type `vimtutor` at the command line - that will get you to the point where you can be reasonably efficient with vi. If you find you like vi and want to learn lots more then read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120/how-to-learn-vim-on-a-high-level/).

Comment: FYI `vi` is a program, that is editing the file `common.mak`.  To use `nano` as the answer suggests, type `nano common.mak`.  Or `gedit common.mak`, etc.   FWIW, `vi` (and `vim`, which is an improved version) are not intuitive, but if you learn them, they are very powerful.  I use `vim` all the time.

Comment: @DavidOneill: thanks - I've updated my answer to make it clearer as you suggest.

Answer (score -1):

use `sudo gedit common.mak` and save it. I have done it in my video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=apoaHf8tPVk