# How do I swap Esc and CapsLock on a command-line system?

Tags: server, keyboard-layout, vim

I want to swap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Escape</kbd> key as specified in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187/88):

> Use the keyboard preferences to swap Caps Lock and Escape - seriously, how often do you use Caps Lock? Using vim you will be using Escape all the time, and having it available on the home row makes a huge difference. With the standard Ubuntu desktop, go through the menus: System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layouts tab. Then hit the "Layout Options" button, click on the triangle next to "Caps Lock key behaviour" and select "Swap ESC and CapsLock".

but, I'm using Ubuntu Server with no gui, so how would I do this from the command line?

Comment: Did you try following instructions provided at http://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux ?

Comment: @VitalieCiubotaru I didn't know that QA existed.  I'll be sure to check it out.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Comment: @izx I will when I test it.  Unfortunately, I haven't had time to.

Answer (score 2):

#### Swapping Esc and CapsLock, *with* combinations, e.g. Ctrl-Esc

- `dumpkeys | grep -P -i  "^keymaps.*|^keycode.*escape|^keycode.*lock" > swap.map`
- *swap.map* should look something like:

  ```
  keymaps 0-127
  keycode   1 = Escape
  keycode  58 = CtrlL_Lock
  keycode  69 = Num_Lock
  keycode  70 = Scroll_Lock
  ```
- Swap the values of keycodes `1` and `58`, while deleting the other `_Lock` lines; leave the first line intact though.
- Try it out with `sudo loadkeys swap.map`
- Assuming it works, simply add this line to `/etc/rc.local`, before the `exit 0` line, to activate the swap upon boot:

  ```
  loadkeys /home/user/swap.map  # or whatever path you chose
  ```

---

See [the source](https://superuser.com/questions/290115/how-to-change-console-keymap-in-linux) for a more general explanation.

Comment: doesn't appear to work over ssh

Comment: Does this work in Wayland?