# How do I swap Escape and Caps Lock in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, capslock

It appears that the keyboard Layout Options that allow things such as "Swap the Escape key and Caps Lock" have disappeared from the keyboard settings in 14.04  Is there another GUI where they can be set?  Or is it [back to dotfiles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53038/how-do-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key)?

Comment: Yeah, they removed most of that in 14.04. If you want it back, report a bug.

Comment: It indeed works, except for VirtualBox, where it does not and one is forced to resort to Xmodmap.

Comment: same but not 14.04 specific: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Install the **GNOME Tweak Tool** (gnome-tweak-tool), under the *Typing* tab there is an option to swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>. This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: gnome tweak tool typing section]

Comment: It would be really cool if you could post a screenshot of the setting.

Comment: It's in "Typing" -> "Caps Key Behavior". Very similar to previous menus. Thank you user268068! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17011409/gnometweaktool.png

Comment: this doesn't work very well (Unity ignores this setting for me).

Comment: This tool is not default tool in Ubuntu installation so better way exists.

Comment: I do not recommend this tool because it is unstable. This answer should not be accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this a bit during my last OS setup, and found a solution. On this setup I had to trudge through the Internet again to find. Let me leave it here for future reference.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (working with 16.04 too), and this is how I remapped my caps lock to escape:

1. Open terminal
2. Open the `/etc/default/keyboard` file with sudo (eg `sudo nano /etc/default/keyboard`)
3. add `caps:swapescape` to the `XKBOPTIONS`. After modification
   the line should like the following

   > XKBOPTIONS="caps:swapescape"

Note that I did not try this with the `caps:swapescape` setting. I used the `caps:escape` setting; i.e. my modification just remaps caps lock to escape but does not map my escape to caps lock.

[My source](http://www.noah.org/wiki/CapsLock_Remap_Howto#Linux_Console)

Answer (score 4):

As I mention in [another similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/692533/23087), the usual way to swap <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is with the following lines in the `~/.Xmodmap` file:

```
clear Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

This should work with all desktop environments (KDE, Gnome) on most common distros (Ubuntu and Debian family, Fedora and RH family).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This is a nice change for using Vim. I am in Xubuntu. Adding this config file is much better than installing a whole new program just for one setting as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: I presume this doesn't work on Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is the one mentioned in this post [how to permanently switch caps lock and esc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363346/how-to-permanently-switch-caps-lock-and-esc) that uses `dpkg-reconfigure` with a few extra steps but setting `"caps:swapescape"` in `xkb-options`