# Use alt as Ctrl and win as alt (keep alt)

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xfce

I am using xfce4 and I am trying to do the following:
I wanna keep the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> as is while also making the <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> act as a ctrl and the win button act as an alt (I don't need the win button)

I've tried to do these in terminal:

```
setxkbmap -option altwin:ctrl_alt_win
```

then this:

```
setxkbmap -option ctrl:aa_ctrl
```

But now the <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> actually does two things at once: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and win action 

(If I press it in emacs I get C-s-)

How do I simply just do that mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I found an amazing answer to this here:  [How do I swap Escape and Caps Lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444714/how-do-i-swap-escape-and-caps-lock-in-14-04).

The answer was to install Tweak. It worked like a charm for me in swapping Caps Lock with Control.

I tried the setxkbmap route and couldn't get it to work, but Tweak worked fine.

BTW, if you are like me, you'll also want to know that the command below will fix your options in setxkbmap that are now probably all screwed up (not that it seems to have an impact):

```
setxkbmap -option ''
```