# How do I remap keys in Ubuntu-16?

Tags: 16.04, vim, keys, remapping

I've been using Ubuntu for about a month now and have recently started using Vim.

I would really like to know how to swap the Caps_Lock and Escape keys but am not sure how.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

I'm aware of this answer: [How persist a remap keys in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749660/how-persist-a-remap-keys-in-ubuntu-16-04) but can't seem to figure it out. Could I get a noob friendly breakdown or something?

Answer (score 0):

If the reason why is to easily use Vim, I recommend you to use `xcape-lbo` instead. Pretty simple to make it work.

Couldn't find the repository but but you can get it through Ubuntu Software.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/788862/460123) that asked how to do this for 14.04. I just found it works for 16.04 too. Have a look at it.