# Swap CTRL and caps lock in tty1 (deeper than gnome)

Tags: keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> swapped in my main desktop environment 14.04 using GNOME Tweak Tool like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/446725/29907).

However, when I'm using tty1, [which I do by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148717/how-do-i-boot-into-the-console-and-then-launch-the-ubuntu-desktop-from-it/148723#148723), my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> are not remapped.

How can I remap my keybindings at the machine/tty1 rather than the Gnome level?

I'm looking for a solution that does not require the x server, so [xkbd options](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html) for example are not an option

Answer (score 1):

Open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and change the line

```
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

to

```
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Comment: This seems to require an x server.  Is there a config that does not?

Comment: @Mittenchops: According to `man keyboard` the file is "shared between X  and  the  console". That would indicate that an X server isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for a simple solution like this for many ages!

Answer (score -1):

Don't. That's not the normal way to do remaps. Remaps nowadays are normally done at the X level and result in the behavior you see, which is usually inconsequential.

Otherwise, anything that's related to X obviously won't do. Package `kbd` and its files in `/etc/kbd/` may provide a solution.

Comment: Wondering why you say "don't". How is system wide keyboard configuration in accordance with `man keyboard` not normal?